# Django show options

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

I have a database filled with values for first_name. I also made a form, which calls for an input of first_name. How can i give the user suggestions as they type of names that are already in the database?

Also, if i have someone entering 2 in one integerfield, and a 3 in another integerfield, how can i autocompute the product and show it in real-time?

Comment: What did you think of? or what does your research say?

Comment: You want to give people suggestions for their first name? Won't they already knew what their own name is?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it will be an admin entering this data in, so they wouldnt know the full names. Plus, this is also to maintain quickness, because they will be entering 50 or so names at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light seems to be what you're looking for. 
It allows the end user to type some characters, after which it will be autocompleted/suggested from what's already in the DB.

For autocomputing the two intergerfields, I'd go for client-side (Javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the auto complete thing, and for autocomputng, that's what I was thinking of too, thanks

Comment: any idea on how to use the package? I dont quite understand the documentation. @SaeX

Comment: @AbhishekPatel: there is an example project that will help out: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project.